# How do I get a List of programs connected to internet?

Tags: internet-connection

How can I get a list of programs that are currently connected to (and are receiving data) from the Internet?

Commands like iftop are good but does not show statistics based on process.

Comment: How about `sudo lsof -i -n -P`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to see apps that are using internet, use something like

```
lsof -P -i -n | cut -f 1 -d " "| uniq | tail -n +2
```

But, if you want to see the actual in/out rate for a certain app, use [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
    netstat -ap
```

will display all TCP, UDP, and (local) Unix-domain sockets, their status, the addresses of the endpoints and the process that owns the socket.  Run it as root to see process information for processes that are not owned by your user.

Comment: Nailed it. +1 was the least I could do to support your answer.